# Where can I find datasets for all confirmed exoplanets, terrestrial exoplanets, and Super-Earth exoplanets?

Tags: exoplanet, spectroscopy, water, raw-data, terrestrial-planets

The NASA Exoplanet Archive has a [Planetary Systems dataset](https://exoplanetarchive.ipac.caltech.edu/cgi-bin/TblView/nph-tblView?app=ExoTbls&config=PS&constraint=default_flag%20%3E0) offers celestial mechanical data for 5,197 confirmed exoplanets. The [Exoplanets Catalog](https://exoplanets.nasa.gov/discovery/exoplanet-catalog/) classifies these exoplanets as terrestrial, super-earth, Neptune-like, or gas giant. Where can I find spectroscopic data, estimates of composition, and/or data on water (or rock) for these exoplanets?

Comment: Most data that we call 'composition' is the mean density interpreted on some equi-density line. There is no unique composition that we know of for most non-gas giants, so if you want scientific scrutiny, then unfortunately there are no answers yet for all those classes of exoplanets.

Answer (score 1):

The slightly more comprehensive catalogue on exoplanets and especially the related research papers is found on http://exoplanet.eu/catalog/
It offers direct link to the publication of each planet and other works which also reference it. Apply your search criteria to this catalogue (it is only different size ranges you want), and then check the links to references. Some will be papers which offer analysis of spectra etc for a select few systems. Most systems won't be observed nor analysed in that regard though. I am not aware of a ready-made list covering all in a fashion like this planets overview table, you will have to check references.

Comment: I would caution against the .eu exoplanet catalog. It seems to be poorly maintained and contains many errors in references as well as in units and data given.